Need to connect a Lipo battery 3.7v to a USB-C style Female connector for Re-charging and
Hobbyist working to productize my product. I do not know electrical circuits.
Need to connect the  lipo-battery 3.7v to the USB-C connector for charging via a USB-C power supply. Any reasons to not directly connect? The circuit would be from the Battery via a JST 1.25 connector >PCB> to a 2 pin USBC-PCB mount (orange)port



What about your charging circuit?

There are many the reasons not to do it.
First is safety around lihium batteries. You seem to have done no research how to use them properly, so you should spend few weeks or months how to design with lithium batteries so that they do not explode or burn down anyone's house, as you can be held liable for designing a dangerous product.

It's not even about USB. You cannot connect lithium batteries direcly to 5V. This has been asked ad infinitum here, people not understanding that they need a charger between a 5V supply, because 5V power supplies are power supplies, not lithium chargers.

You cannot use USB C connector like that. There can be no voltage fed back to a receptacle, unless the cable detect circuitry has detected that there is a device connected that requires power, so not USB compliant at all. You also should not use the connector shield as the return path for current, there is a ground pin for that. Also you cannot leave the CC pins disconnected. No other device which has a receptacle can detect your product through a C to C cable.



Yes, there is a big reason not to do this. Applying 5 volts directly to a LiPo is likely to destroy the battery and possibly cause a fire!
You MUST use a proper charging circuit to charge any lithium battery. Any battery that connects directly to a voltage source for charging has a charging circuit built-in.
Please, if you don't know what you are doing, don't try to DIY a lithium battery charger!

What is the simplest form of battery management. low cost and small. I would need to add into the PCB board design in the image
